# Open Office is not showing in English, even though the English language is selected

Tags: language, openoffice, user-interface, openoffice-calc, translation

I don't understand what happened with this Open Office installation. It's on a college computer (Linux), so I can't do a reinstallation without admin access.

I have English language selected in Language setting, than also Greek language is showing. See below:

[image: Open office options]

When typing, it's showing *English alphabet* in the Excel **cell**, but it is showing *Greek alphabet* in the **Formula bar**. See below:

[image: Open Office Calc screenshot]

How can I change the User Interference to English and showing English alphabet in formula bar?

Answer (score 1):

The texts are not Greek, just simple transliterations from Latin to Greek alphabet. So this looks like [Pseudo-Localization](https://superuser.com/q/1340277/241386)

> [image: Windows pseudo-localization]
>
> That's pseudolocalization used to test compatibility across different languages. Microsoft and others have been doing it for years now.
>
> During most development, the only language that has 100% coverage is en-us because 100% of primary development on Windows is done in Redmond.
>
> Running non-US locales on insider builds, especially in Skip Ahead and Fast Ring, are only shipped with en-US and Pseudoloc'd locales. OP is definitely using en-UK ("programme") which means that a large number of strings are probably pseudoloc'd. This helps identify non-localized strings
>
> it's weird enough that it won't make it into retail through an automated check (there's a lot of zero-width spaces in there, too, which aren't allowed in normal translations for the most part).
>
> [Strange font/characters in some apps](https://www.reddit.com/r/windowsinsiders/comments/8wj2jl/strange_fontcharacters_in_some_apps/)

---

From the interface I can see that all characters are the direct analogs of the corresponding English character in the Greek alphabet. For example

- *ΣΥΜ* → SUM. Υ and Μ are upper case Upsilon and Mu, not Latin Y and M
- The options dialog has *Δεϕαυλτ - Ενγλιση (ΥΣΑ)* which transliterates to ***Default - English (USA)***. Similarly *Εναβλεδ* → ***Enabled***,  *Λοχαλε* → ***Locale***
- The menu reads *Εδιτ ςιεω Ινσερτ Φορματ Τοολσ Δατα Ωινδοω Ηελπ* which are simply ***Edit View Insert Format Tools Data Window Help*** transliterated
- And many more...

They're not Greek language at all, considering Tools menu in Greek is *εργαλεία μενού* that I can find even with zero knowledge of Greek language. Below is a menu in real Greek

[image: Greek menu]

There is another one who has exactly your problem when [his French locale is translated letter-by-letter to Greek characters](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/79551/hi-my-computer-language-is-french-however-all-the-lo-menus-are-in-greek-but-not-real-greek-translation-of-each-french-letter-in-a-greek-letter-thanks/)

In Libre Office a [pseudo language called qtz](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/LOWN/1) is used while testing. In fact the language codes [qaa](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/language-code-qaa.3426172/)-[qtz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes) are reserved for used internally by ISO-639 standard (like testing purposes) and you can find some examples of them on the internet like [How to remove 'Unknown Locale (qaa-Latn)' from fresh Windows Server installation?](https://superuser.com/q/1333637/241386)

I'm not sure about Open Office but the same thing should happen. Probably you've used some beta or internal testing version, or the pseudo testing language was accidentally released which may be quickly solved by updating the application. Or try changing the interface language to another language and see if it displays correctly

For more information read

- [Inside WDG – Localization Process](https://windows10forgeeks.wordpress.com/2016/04/01/inside-wdg-localization-process/)
- [Localizability Testing - Globalization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/testing/localizability-testing)
- [What is Pseudo-Localization?](http://blog.globalizationpartners.com/what-is-pseudo-localization.aspx)
- [Pseudo English looking characters used in Windows 10 Insider Preview](https://superuser.com/q/1340277/241386)
- [Android - Test your app with pseudolocales](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/pseudolocales)

  [image: Pseudolocale on Android]