# Remove languages from language bar not listed in settings (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, locale

In my Windows 10 installation, the little language switcher in the task bar is cluttered with keyboard layouts / locale settings I never use:

[image: Windows 10 language switcher in task bar]

So I go to language settings to try and remove them -- but there, only the two I actually want appear. The ones I am trying to remove are only listed in the language bar, but not in the settings.

[image: Windows 10 language settings]

My end goal is to only have German (Swiss), i.e. *Deutsch (Schweiz)* and English (US), i.e *Englisch (Vereinigte Staaten)*, and to have the US Layout as the default. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove 'Unknown Locale (qaa-Latn)' from fresh Windows Server installation?](https://superuser.com/questions/1333637/how-to-remove-unknown-locale-qaa-latn-from-fresh-windows-server-installation) or [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1092246/how-to-prevent-windows-10-from-automatically-adding-keyboard-layouts-i-e-us-ke?noredirect=1&lq=1) question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the method I just used and your case seems similar:

- Win+R: Regedit
- Go to: `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload`

You should see a list of values like this
[List of Keyboard Layouts in the Registery editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhUec.png)

Visit this page to see what the data values correspond too
(in my case 0000040c is French)

[Keyboard Identifiers Identifiers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values?view=windows-11#keyboard-identifiers)

- Add/Remove the keyboard languages you need

I'd probably advise only removing the extra ones here and adding them in the Windows settings as you'd normally do.

Answer (score 1):

Open Start.
Search for Windows PowerShell, right-click the top result, and select Run as administrator.
Type the following command to list the languages currently installed on your device and press Enter:Get-WinUserLanguageList

$LangList = Get-WinUserLanguageList

$MarkedLang = $LangList | where LanguageTag -eq "en-IN"

$LangList.Remove($MarkedLang)

Set-WinUserLanguageList $LangList -Force