# How to remove 'Unknown Locale (qaa-Latn)' from Windows 10 logon screen?

Tags: windows-10, input-languages

Article [How to remove 'Unknown Locale (qaa-Latn)' from fresh Windows Server installation?](https://superuser.com/questions/1333637/how-to-remove-unknown-locale-qaa-latn-from-fresh-windows-server-installation) answers how to remove the qaa-Latn language from the UI once the user has logged on, that is, from the input indicator, etc.

However, on the Windows logon screen there's a also a choice of languages/keyboards and I haven't been able to remove it from there, not even after removing the language from

```
Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Control Panel\International\User Profile - Languages
Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Control Panel\International\User Profile\qaa-Latn
```

Answer (score 0):

Uff, solved.

In `Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Control Panel\International\User Profile System Backup` in `en-DE` (or some such) there was a reference to a 0x2000 keyboard which was also listed in `Computer\HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload` and `Computer\HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Substitutes`. Removing the key from `Profile System Backup` gave the success.

I also did a scan through the registry to ensure qaa-Latn was gone.

Comment: Nice! FIY these qaa locales are fallback names for transient keyboard LANGIDs.
0x2000 - LOCALE_TRANSIENT_KEYBOARD1 - "qaa-Latn",
0x2400 - LOCALE_TRANSIENT_KEYBOARD2 - "qab-Latn",
0x2800 - LOCALE_TRANSIENT_KEYBOARD3 - "qac-Latn",
0x2C00 - LOCALE_TRANSIENT_KEYBOARD4 - "qad-Latn".

Comment: These may appear due to the bugs in Windows or in 3rd party software. In normal these IDs are allocated and used in place of lcid for languages without lcids. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/locale-names#the-deprecation-of-lcids