# Weird folders in event viewer. Can't tell if they’re legit or something else

Tags: windows-11, event-viewer, windows-11-preview, windows-11-v22h2

The Microsoft folders in my event viewer looks weird, I do not know how to describe this better

[image]

Any idea if these are legit or if I should be worried?

My current Windows version is:

- Édition Windows 11 Entreprise Insider Preview Version 22H2
- Build du système d’exploitation 25236.1010
  Expérience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.25236.1010.0

Comment: pretty weird - is the whole system language French? Try running this in powershell and see if those log names are actually wrong, or just displaying weird: `Get-WinEvent -ListLog * | select LogName`. Another spot to check is the registry - try this, and see if the normal name exists: `Get-Item HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\System\Microsoft-Windows-EnhancedStorage-EhStorTcgDrv`

Comment: @Cpt.Whale the whole language system is French yes, also when querying using powershell everything looks fine.

Comment: if they look normal in powershell, then they should be fine. Event Viewer may just be having trouble displaying the folder names for some reason, but the actual logging should be working normally. I have no idea why it would accent every character though, pretty weird.

Comment: It went back to normal after windows got an update, so I suppose it was just a glitch, thanks a lot

Comment: FWIW, this stuff is formally called [Pseudolocalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudolocalization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are missing translations. Preview builds of Windows use such mangled English text as placeholders for actual translations because they are easy to spot and still readable. Final builds should have these replaced with proper localized strings.

Comment: Good info! But already covered in [this other question](https://superuser.com/q/1340277/167207); flagged this one as a dupe. This stuff is formally called [Pseudolocalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudolocalization).

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I knew I saw it explained somewhere on SU, but didn't know how to search for it. Thanks, voted to close as a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

It went back to normal after windows got an update, so I suppose it was just a glitch